# Xcode crashes when trying to login with developer Apple ID

Tags: xcode, xcode7, crash-reports, apple-id

Xcode crashes when trying to login with developer Apple ID in preferences.

Freshly installed Xcode 7.1.1 and Xcode 7.1. Both crash.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Crash log here: [crash log](http://paste.org.ru/?ac3nw5)

Comment: I have gotten used to the crashes since I updated to Xcode 7.0. They are still unstable.